# Recibir json en Python de PHP y extraer datos

Tags: python, json, parsear

Una api me envía un JSON, lo recibo en PHP y lo envió a Phayton para procesarlo, el problema es al convertirlo a objeto para extraer los datos, da error todo el rato
me da estos errores:

> ERROR: (,
>   JSONDecodeError('Expecting property name enclosed in double quotes:
>   line 1 column 2 (char 1)',), )

Codigo PHP:

```
<?php header('Content-Type: application/json'); 
ob_start(); 
$json = file_get_contents('php://input'); 
$request = json_decode($json, true); 
$peticion = json_encode($request);
ob_end_clean();
$request = json_decode($data, true); 
$peticion = json_encode($request);
exec('sct.py ' . $peticion);
?>
```

Codigo Python:

```
import json
import urllib.request
import urllib.parse
import sys

print("Content-Type: text/html\n")
try:
    data1 = json.loads(json.dumps(sys.argv[1]))
    data = json.loads(''.join(data1).replace("'", '"'))


    #ahora recorremos el json en busqueda de parametro requerido

    dataLista =([x['parameters'] for x in data['queryResult']['outputContexts']])

    url = 'https://api.telegram.org/bot/sendMessage?chat_id=&text=P2: '+ json.dumps(dataLista[0])
    f = urllib.request.urlopen(url)
    print(f.read().decode('utf-8'))

    #cambiamos de lista a diccionario
    dataDiccionario = dict (dataLista[0])

    #declaramos que lista ordenes es una lista de valores(values) de dataDiccionario
    ordenes = dataDiccionario.values()


    #recorremos el diccionario en busqueda de objeto(str) que termina en .original'
    for objeto in dataDiccionario:
        #si la clave(str) termina con 'original'
        if objeto[-8:] == 'original':
            #imrimimos el valor de la clave
            datafinal = dataDiccionario[objeto]
            print (dataDiccionario[objeto])
            url = 'https://api.telegram.org/bot/sendMessage?chat_id=&text=P3: '+ dataDiccionario[objeto]
            f = urllib.request.urlopen(url)
            print(f.read().decode('utf-8') )
```

El Json que debo procesar:

```
{
"responseId":"6c3008ec-8614-4e04-931c-aea5b5c4b986",
"queryResult":{
    "queryText":"s\u00ed","action":"BajarSubirEquipaje.BajarSubirEquipaje-yes",
    "parameters":[],
    "allRequiredParamsPresent":true,
    "fulfillmentText":"Confirmado! Ahora vendr\u00e1 un botones.(se env\u00eda la informaci\u00f3n sobre botones al ordenador de recepci\u00f3n o cualquier otro dispositivo deseado)",
    "fulfillmentMessages":[{
        "text":{
            "text":["Confirmado! Ahora vendr\u00e1 un botones.(se env\u00eda la informaci\u00f3n sobre botones al ordenador de recepci\u00f3n o cualquier otro dispositivo deseado)"]
        }
    }],
    "outputContexts":[{
        "name":"projects/bajarsubirequipaje-followup",
        "lifespanCount":1,
        "parameters":{
            "bajarSubirEquipaje.original":"Bajar equipaje",
            "necesitoCosas2.original":"",
            "bajarSubirEquipaje":"bajar equipaje",
            "necesitoCosas2":""
        }
    },
        {
        "name":"projects\/generic",
        "lifespanCount":3,
        "parameters":{
            "bajarSubirEquipaje.original":"Bajar equipaje",
            "telegram_chat_id":000006,
            "necesitoCosas2.original":"",
            "bajarSubirEquipaje":"bajar equipaje",
            "necesitoCosas2":""}
        }   
    ],
    "intent":{
        "name":"projects\-42ff96b382db",
        "displayName":"BajarSubirEquipaje - yes"
        },
        "intentDetectionConfidence":1,
        "diagnosticInfo":[],
        "languageCode":"es"
},
"originalDetectIntentRequest":{
    "payload":{
        "data":{
            "update_id":277748595,
            "callback_query":{
                "data":"s\u00ed","from":{
                    "language_code":"ru",
                    "id":423485916,
                    "is_bot":false,
                    "first_name":"Sergio",
                    "username":"SergioBogatsky"
                },
                "id":"1818858163814866308",
                "message":{
                    "date":17781646,
                    "chat":{
                        "id":423477716,
                        "type":"private",
                        "first_name":"nn",
                        "username":"Snn"
                    },
                    "message_id":72777,
                    "from":{
                        "id":4958648491,
                        "is_bot":true,
                        "first_name":"UC",
                        "username":"UC"
                    },
                    "text":"\u00bfDe acuerdo. \u00bfConfirma Usted que quiere que un botones le ayude con equipaje?"
                },
                "chat_instance":"-781907969540610"
            }
        },
    "source":"telegram"
    }
},
"session":"projects\6-9bb2-711de53137cb"
```

}

Comment: Hola Djdadi43, ¿Podrías mostrar el contenido en crudo del argumento que le pasas al script (`sys.argv[1]`) para poder reproducir el problema?

Comment: ya esta acgtualizada la pregunta